# Why do we get the same result ,2-ball, for both sets, although they are not equal?

Tags: general-topology

{${(x,y):x^2+y^2<1}$} and {$(x,y):\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1$} $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ These are the sets, but why do we get the same result why isnt the square root not changing the result ?

Comment: If $A,B\geq0$, then the inequalities $A^2<B^2$ and $A<B$ are equivalent. In your case $A=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^2}$ and $B=\sqrt{1}$.

Comment: For any $t \geq 0$ the conditions $t <1$ and $\sqrt t <1$ are equivalent. $1-t=(1-\sqrt t) (1+\sqrt t)$ and $1+\sqrt t >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the square root, you should realise that the first set is the same as
$$\{(x,y):\sqrt{x^2+y^2}< \sqrt{1}\}$$

Now, what is $\sqrt{1}$?

Comment: lol, it is so obvious, dunno what i was thinking of. As taking the square root or squaring would be an equivalence

Answer (score 1):

Because $1^2=1$.  When you have $\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \lt 1$, both sides are positive and squaring is monotonic, so you can square both sides to get $x^2+y^2 \lt 1^2$

Comment: this probably only works for 1 right ?

Comment: That is right.  If it were $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt 3$ it would be $x^2+y^2\lt 9$

Comment: right thanks, 1 and 0 are the only numbers it would possibly work where as for 0, it wouldnt make sense

Comment: could we say that the sets are equal ?

Comment: Yes, we can.  The same points are members of both